# Confidence in Multinomial Distributions

Tags: statistics

a response to a survey question is either yes or no.  The responses are divided into ten categories, based on other information.  So in category 1, there's 341 yes and 1023 no, cat 2 128 yes and 744 no, etc.

I would like to calculate some sort of confidence in the proportion of yes/no over the categories, like a confidence interval saying that for category 1, we are 95% sure the true value falls within this range.  Do I perform either a Chi Squared test or a Simultaneous Multinomial Confidence Interval?

Comment: perhaps a two-tail t-statistic test could be used to compare against the overall mean?